# Google Pixel C stuck on Booting

Tags: root-access, boot-loop, kiosk-mode

We are developing a Kiosk application using Pixel C as the kiosk device.

To achieve the kiosk mode for application, we first root the device, then use "dpm set-device-owner", granting the application device owner permission.

Devices operate 24/7.

All of the devices run same Android 7.1.1 version (build number N4F26T) and supposedly same security patch. Supposedly because Android patches won’t apply to rooted devices, because system is unable to verify checksums or something.

After some time (~ 6 months), devices started to behave strange, i.e., not able to receive/send network requests, automatically disconnect from known Wi-Fi access point. Some devices event stuck in boot loop after rebooting the device using the built-in “reboot” command.

We think that this is some kind of hardware issue, because Pixel Cs weren’t supposed to operate this way besides internetz are full of complaints about Pixel C, or a software bug, which with our operation mode (rooted + device owner) has lead to this state.

Did anyone come across to this kind of issue with the tablet?

Comment: Have you tried using the [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management) instead of rooting the device and using `dpm set-device-owner`?

Comment: @Fred, thanks for the information about the Android Management API, but at the time we didn't have knowledge of it :) Our app was already developed using the device owner thingie.